# Android How to compress the picture, and do not read to the memory?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I found if want to compress picture,everyone would read to Bitmap first.but I wan't to read ,just edit picture file, then the picture file can be smaller.

The java has the class,but it can't use to android. Has any source code can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso Library for the image processing purpose.Just like this:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(R.drawable.add_icon)
                    .resize(130, 130).placeholder(R.drawable.no_images).into(imgPratientImage;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Use following code to get image from byte array

```
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length, options);
                // Calculate inSampleSize
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length, options);
                int dimension = getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(bitmap);
                bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dimension, dimension);
```

Where `imageByteArray` is actually byte array that you can get from the server. You can use other methods, I written this one only as example. Variable `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are desired width and height of the picture.